# vi to delete from the beginning of the line till the cursor

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

How can we use vim to delete characters from the beginning of the line till the cursor.
Say, we have a string "hello world" while the cursor is on "w". How can we delete from "h" till "w".

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try `d0`. `0` denotes the beginning of the line.

Comment: If you are in insert mode you can use `<C-U>`.

Comment: not sure what happened but when I enter the d0, the line got deleted from my cursor location to start of the line.

Comment: @YouAreAwesome That is _exactly_ what `d0` does, and what OP was asking for.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276398/3277592

Answer (score 72):

I believe that the following should work (<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>):

```
d^
```

This assumes that you only want to delete to the `h` even if there is white space in front of it.  It will leave the white space.

Answer (score 17):

TLDR:
**The easiest way is to do the following**

- use the navigate mode
- set the cursor at whatever line you want

  > - press dgg - this will remove everything from cursor to the beginning
  > - press dG - this will remove all the lines from cursor till the end of the doc.

**But why?**

```
gg - goes to the begin of the document
G - navigates at its very end
d - delete mode
```

I was also looking for some combinations with the notation of d and line number, and when you are editing huge files like GB in size I found it bit annoying.
Like to remove first 3 lines you need to do this **:0,d3**, but when the docu is over 1mln lines its tough for my eyes to read this crap...

Answer (score 6):

The other suggestions didn't work for me, but I used visual mode to achieve this.

I moved the cursor to the position I wanted to delete through, and hit <kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode. Then I hit <kbd>^</kbd> to select back to the beginning of the current line, and then <kbd>d</kbd> to delete all of the highlighted text.

Answer (score 6):

If you're in insert mode and you want to delete to the start of the line (and stay in insert mode), you can use <kbd>CTRL+u</kbd>

This matches the bash meaning of <kbd>CTRL+u</kbd> as shown [here](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html).

To get the vim documentation simply type

```
:help i_CTRL-U
```

in the command line.

> CTRL-U          Delete all entered characters before the cursor in the
> current
> line.  If there are no newly entered characters and
> 'backspace' is not empty, delete all characters before the
> cursor in the current line.
> If C-indenting is enabled the indent will be adjusted if the
> line becomes blank.
> See i_backspacing about joining lines.
> i_CTRL-I i_ i_Tab

Comment: Since you are in insert mode you have to add the prefix '_i' to your help command.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your cursor is on "w", you'll be deleting backwards...

You can use vim's "till" <kbd>t</kbd>, but moving backwards it requires an uppercase <kbd>T</kbd>.
The same works for "find" <kbd>f</kbd> moving backwards it's <kbd>F</kbd>.

So, in your case, you can delete back "till" the quote symbol:
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

Or, if to prefer targeting/finding the "h":
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

Try jumping around first without the delete to get a feel for it, then you can just layer in the action as the prefix.

Happy Vimming! :)

Answer (score 0):

> not sure what happened but when I enter the d0, the line got deleted from my
> cursor location to start of the line. – YouAreAwesome Dec 14 '17 at 6:43

Confirming that this worked. It seems to be the simplest method. (You can't upvote a comment, so I'm adding it as an answer in it's own right.)

Example: In .ssh/authorized_keys, I had:

> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user "centos" rather than the user "root".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2...

This is the way Amazon AWS keeps you from logging in as root.

I put the cursor on the s in ssh-rsa and hit 'd0' and got a perfect delete to beginning of line.