# Deleting to beginning of line - d0 leaves extra space

Tags: vim

I am trying to delete an indented line to the beginning of the line, with `d0`, but that leaves an extra space that I must delete with `x`.

The use case is that often I want to insert a blank line between two lines, and yes, I could use 'o' or 'O' and 'Esc' but often I enter insert mode out of habit and enter a line.  The `autoindent` in `vim` adds a line with extra space (even with `smartindent`) so I am left with some dangling space that I have to delete with 'd0x'.

The extra 'x' seems awkward given that 'D' deletes to the end of the line leaving no extra space, and yes I could use '0D' to do the same with in one less stroke.  But I would like your opinions as to the best approach for this situation.  Thanks.

[image: Example]

Comment: I remove all trailing white-spaces on save. I have my own implementation, but there is also a plugin: [vim-DeleteTrailingWhitespace](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-DeleteTrailingWhitespace)

Answer (score 4):

Addressing the very specific point of why `d0` leaves an extra space: The [`0`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#0) motion is an [exclusive](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#exclusive) motion, which means the last character towards the end of the region is excluded from the operation.

You can use the [`v`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#o_v) modifier to toggle the characterwise motion and make it inclusive:

```
dv0
```

This should remove all the characters from the beginning of the line, including the one under the cursor.

Comment: I can offer some workarounds. For instance, you can use `==` to trigger auto-formatting (will use `indentexpr` on Python source code), or even `=k` from the `for` line to format the current line and the one above. The best though, is to use `O<Esc>` to insert a blank line above the current one, that will not leave trailing whitespace on the blank line.

Comment: thanks so much for answering that specific question about d0, it makes a lot of sense now.  And thanks for the python source code tips!

Comment: If `0` motion is exclusive then why the the first character of the line is deleted? If we are on the end of the line and press `d0`, the last character of the line is not deleted while the first character of the line is deleted. Are motion always interpreted from left to right?

Comment: @adosar See `:help exclusive`, which says _"When
exclusive, the last character **towards the end of the buffer** is not included."_ Since the target of `0` will always be the _start_ (since it's a movement towards the start of the buffer), the character at the other end is the one that will not be included. The first paragraph in my answer addresses that, please take a look again and see if it's clear to you now.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some complicated thing you want to do in `vim` with minimal keystrokes, the usual approach is to just create a macro for it and bind that macro to a specific key sequence.

For example, for your use case of inserting a blank unindented line, you could just bind to `O<ESC>0D` (or whatever other key sequence you need). You can test this with the keystrokes (in normal mode, and `<ESC>` is a single press of the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, not the five individual characters):

```
qdO<ESC>0Dq
```

Then just go to some line in your file, enter `@d` and, voila, an unindented blank line.

To make this permanent, just add it to your `vimrc` file:

```
let @d='O<ESC>0D'
```

where, if you're editing it with `vim`, <kbd>ESC</kbd> can be entered as <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>.

---

Another possibility is to just not worry about indents until some point in the future. By all means, use whatever commands you desire to give yourself a blank line (possibly indented) but either fix that before final write by deleting all trailing tabs and spaces:

```
:g/[ <TAB>]\+$/s///
```

or run a script on all files to fix this in a batch operation (even better if this is done as part of automatic pre-checks before source code commit), for example:

```
find . -name *.cpp -exec sed -iE 's/[ \t]+$//' {} \;
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  I am always worried about adding macros because I might end up in a situation without my ~/.vimrc, so any suggestions that don't require a special configuration would be ideal.

Comment: @FrankieY.Liu, it seems to me that you either have to use *some* special configuration, or use *only* the commands that `vim` gives you out of the box. If you only want the latter, then you'll need to use the four-keystroke option. In any case, I try to make sure my `vimrc`, and certain other important configs, are accessible from *anywhere.*

Comment: Thank you for giving me a couple of ways of tackling this problem.

Comment: For the next to last suggestion (g///): do you map it to a macro or create a command for the string replacement, if a command, what do you map it to (usually) a <leader> key or something else?

Comment: @Frankie, I usually just type it in but, since I've been using `vi` in some form or another for the better part of 40 years, I probably remember a tad more than most people :-) What you could *possibly* do is create macro `@x` to do this and `ZZ` to save and exit. Then, entering `@x` in normal mode would fix the lines, save, and exit.